# Items past 100 aren't showing up on my dweller in the wasteland. Is that the limit?

Tags: ios, fallout-shelter

My dwellers don't seem to be able to carry more than 100 items in the wasteland. Does anyone know if that's only for show or does anyone know if that's all they'll bring back when they return?

Also it seems that any items found in the scrolling text aren't being added to the list of items below once they reach that limit.

Comment: Is anyone else's reaction: OMG You have a dweller with 100 items still alive in the wasteland AND you took the time to count them out!?

Comment: @James I have a small army of max-SPECIAL, max-level dwellers in the wasteland returning mostly crap. I think the problem is they are capping out at 100 items before they get to the point legendaries are dropping.

Comment: I remember reading this was a bug but I don't remember where...